# Is it possible to get a return code from SFDX command executions?

Tags: salesforcedx, python

I have a Python script where I run SFDX commands using subprocess module, here is part of my code:

`query = run(f'sfdx force:data:soql:query -u myOrg -q "SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger"', shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT).stdout
print(query)`

Here is how I validate an update:

`update = run(f'sfdx force:data:record:update -u MyOrg -s User -w Email='abc@abc.com' -v Email='xyz@xyz.com', shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT).stdout
if 'Succesfully' in update:
    print('Success')`

The thing is, the only way I can work with the result of any SFDX command is to read the output of stdout, which is a string, and then I have to parse it to find the substring that I need.

Also, to validate the success or failure of an Update, I find a 'Successfully' substring within the output. Is there a way I can get a return code from Salesforce, or perhaps an output in json format or dictionary type so I can refer to the records and values instead of reading the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard CLI commands accept a [--json flag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_plugins.meta/sfdx_cli_plugins/cli_plugins_customize_parameters_global.htm?search_text=json) which returns JSON (and seems to include a status code).